# Whenever i write some code in Chianlink VRF fulfillRandomWords function it does not get updated

Tags: solidity, blockchain, chainlink, randomness, vrf

- I have already set my Subscriptions for Chainlink
- Added consumer and subscription have sufficient Link as well
- No Error occurs whenever I call the `requestRandomWords` function
- The chainlink subscriptions page `fulfillments` is also updated.
- But still, the `fulfillRandomWords` function is not executing the code
- `s_randomWords` `tokenCounter` nothing is updating its value

**Chainlink VRF V1 is working fine but V1 is deprecated now, So I am using Chainlink VRF V2 but it is not executing the code in the given function. Although when I do the same thing in Remix it is working fine.**

[image: Subsctription and consumers on the chainlink]
[image: Transaction History on etherscan]

```
fulfillRandomWords(uint256 requestId, uint256[] memory randomWords)
    internal
    override
{
    tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 1;
    s_randomWords = randomWords;
    s_one_r = randomWords[0];
    address dogOwner = requestIdToSender[s_requestId];
    string memory tokenURI = requestIdToTokenURI[s_requestId];
    uint256 newItemId = tokenCounter;
    checkUri = tokenURI;
    //This newItemId should have to be a randomWords
    _safeMint(dogOwner, newItemId);
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

    Breed breed = Breed(s_randomWords[0] % 3);
    tokenIdToBreenter code hereed[newItemId] = breed;
    requestIdToTokenId[s_requestId] = newItemId;

    emit FulfillEvent(tokenCounter, s_one_r, tokenURI);
    //randomResult = randomNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72384572/whenever-i-write-some-code-in-chianlink-vrf-fulfillrandomwords-function-it-does

Please continue posting on that thread, and update your question if you have any updates directly there.  That way its easier for people to find, read and use the resource.